# Disable keydown during animation

Tags: jquery, binding, callback, keydown, jquery-events

I'm using the following code to enable the user to show or hide a photo description (`#photoinfo`) and a menu (`.slidetable`) using the up and down arrow keys. If one of these two divs is already open, pressing the opposite arrow closes that div before opening the other.

```
$(document).unbind('keypress');
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 38:
        if ($('#photoinfo').is(".open")) {
            closeInfo();
        }
        else if ($('.slidetable').is(".open")) {
            closeSlide2();
            openInfo();
        }
        else {
            openInfo();
        }
        break;
    case 40:
        if ($('.slidetable').is(".open")) {
            closeSlide();
        }
        else if ($('#photoinfo').is(".open")) {
            closeInfo();
            openSlide();
        }
        else {
            openSlide();
        }
        break;
    }
    return false;
});​
```

It seems to work, only the problem is if two arrows are pressed at the same time, or one after the other, both divs open, overlapping each other. I'm looking for a way to essentially unbind the `keydown` function after the first animation initiates, and rebind the `keydown` function once it finishes. I'm a jQuery novice, so maybe this isn't the best way of doing this. What is the easiest way of preventing the other function from firing during the animation?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a boolean (isAnimating) to true before you fire an animation and once it completes set it to false. At the top of keydown just say

```
if(isAnimating)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

I don't remember the syntax to have a function call at the end of the animation but it's in jQuery's documentation

Comment: $(this).animate({options}, duration, callback);

Comment: It's sad I couldn't remember that

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Would the implementation of your answer look something like this, or am I way off?

```
$(document).unbind('keypress'); 
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if(isAnimating)
            {
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }

            switch (event.keyCode) {

                case 38: var isAnimating = true; 

                        if ($('#photoinfo').is(".open")) {
                            closeInfo();

                        }

                        else if ($('.slidetable').is(".open")) {
                            closeSlide2();
                            openInfo();

                        }

                        else {
                            openInfo();


                        } break;


                case 40: var isAnimating = true;
                        if ($('.slidetable').is(".open")) {
                              closeSlide();

                        }

                        else if ($('#photoinfo').is(".open")) {
                            closeInfo();
                            openSlide();

                        }

                        else {
                            openSlide();

                        } break;    

            }
            var isAnimating = false;                                
            return false;
});
```

Comment: Generally but isAnimating should be global. And you'd have to reset it to false inside the animation functions openSlide/closeSlide when those animations complete. The idea is while animating, nothing else can animate, and once the current animation it complete it allows other animations to start. Kind of like a lock.

Comment: I'm trying everything and not getting anywhere. You're saying I would put if(isAnimating)
            {
              event.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
in the $(document).ready function in order to making it global? When I do this step by itself, already the page locks up and won't let any click or keypress function work. What should I be doing?